# Lektor server doubles subfolder in url without obvious reason

Tags: lektor

I am trying to export an existing php-based dynamic webpage into a lektor project which up to now really worked well.

Unfortunately one problem is giving me a headache:
While my navigation works perfectly with every page and subpage, links to subpages in the content section don't.

E.g. if I set a relative path like

```
[My Link to Subpage](/peter/personalinfo)
```

it is correctly shown in the browser view. If I hover the mouse over the link the browser shows the correct url 127.0.0.1:5000/peter/personalinfo.
But if I click it I get

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

and the url in the address field shows

```
127.0.0.1:5000/peter/peter/personalinfo
```

So I click the correct url but the browser calls the wrong url and of course can't find anything there.
I don't understand how this doubling can happen. I naively would expect that if I clicked a link the browser would exactly look at that address. But it seems like the server is redirecting to the malformed url. And yes, it does so with any link to a subpage.

the navigation looks like this:

```
Home
News
Peter
-- Personalinfo
-- Contact
-- Portfolio
Bob
-- Personalinfo
-- Contact
-- Portfolio
```

Any idea why this happens and how to change it?

*Update:* The problem doesn't appear with the built static page on a webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an open issue ([#997](https://github.com/lektor/lektor/issues/997)) that is already fixed and will be released soon. But you can fix this yourself, just append a slash at the end of your link `[My Link to Subpage](/peter/personalinfo/)`